# Staging/production deployment on WordPress MultiSite

Tags: staging

Looking to create a staging process for changes to our WordPress MultiSite. We are running several different templates between the sites in our network, but we'd love to use a stage site to test changes to those sites in the network. We're running 3.7.1. Our themes were built in-house. We run a number of plugins, some network-wide, some on certain sites in the network. We've set up a directory on the webhosting server to run it called /staging. We're not sure where to begin, though.

Comment: Well, we're not sure to where we should begin either. You'll have to have some starting point for us, else it will get _very_ opinionated (and therefore closed).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by doing a full filesystem and database and put the same thing running on your staging environment under a different domain. Don't do configuration under this installation or if you do bare in mind that changes will be lost since you want to periodically sync the production database with the staging one to make sure the environment remains similar. Ideally it should be as close as possible to your production one.

Don't forget to deactivate auto-updates on production in order to test everything before going live.